# Why won't my PC sleep or hibernate from a timer?

Tags: windows-10, sleep, hibernate, timer

I previously had issues with my Windows 10 PC sleeping and instantly waking up due to LAN, which I fixed. The computer will sleep and hibernate fine when told directly, and doesn't wake itself up.

Now the timer for the display works fine, but the timers for sleeping and hibernation do nothing. I've tried unplugging the ethernet and USB cables, along with the display and audio, but still nothing.

I've run powercfg/energy which said that the MoUSO core worker process and the print spooler were preventing sleep, but when I ended them it still didn't help. I have also tried turning off the antivirus. Running powercfg/requests didn't turn anything up, either.

In another thread, someone said that if the display turned off first then the sleep timer wouldn't work. Turning the display timer to 'never' and the sleep timer to 1 min still did nothing.

Finally, I tried booting in safe mode - where it appears the computer can't sleep, but can hibernate and turn the display off - and only then did it hibernate from the timer!

So now I need to find a way to make it work when not in safe mode before it drives me up the wall. Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.